# "rcorr" function and multiple testing correction

Tags: correlation, hmisc

Do p values produced by rcorr have to be corrected for multiple comparison or does this function account for multiple testing?

In the output of p-values table I have correlations significant at different levels (e.g. .05, .001) and I don't seem to be able to find if these are corrected for multiple testing.